# Is there a way using BigInteger for iteration?

Tags: java, math, biginteger, notation

Does `BigInteger` only have `equals` for comparison?
Are there substitutes for math notation like < (greater than) or < (less than)?
^Answered!

now i want to know, is there a way using `BigInteger` in iteration such as `while` and `for`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigInteger%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use math notation, in fact I wouldn't get in the habit of using == either, I'm fairly sure that unless they used some serious trickery it will fail.

```
a = new BigInteger(500);

b = a;
if( a == b ) 
    will always be true

b=new BigInteger(500);
if( a == b )
    will never be true

if( a.equals(b) )
    will always work fine.
```

Java isn't a great language for this kind of stuff--I really love Java but ended up having a lot of trouble implementing a Complex class and then implementing a matrix that could hold and manipulate the complex class.

My solution was to use Java to create the core classes then use Groovy to create the classes that used the core classes.  If you follow certain naming patterns, then you can use any operators on any class.

Or if you just want to mess with big numbers simply use groovy and don't even declare a type for your variables--it will automatically promote them to whatever you need.

Comment: `BigInteger` can only hold whole numbers, so `5.5` won't work. You're probably thinking of `BigDecimal`. And even if it were `BigDecimal`: using [the constructor that takes a double is almost always a bad idea!](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double))

Comment: Damn it, thank you.  Wasn't thinking--I wanted to use some bizarre numbers because I think Sun actually does a trick that makes BigInt(1 through 10) actually use the same reference through some kind of dark magic.  Oh well, will go fix.

Comment: Also: note that there is no dark magic in Java that lets `new` return anything but a new object. So your second `a==b` check can't ever return `true`. Also `b.add(100);` has no visible effect, as `add()` doesn't modify the `BigInteger` instance (it's immutable, after all), but returns the result as a new object instead.

Comment: The "black magic" of reusing small `BigInteger` instances works for `BigIniteger.valueOf()` rather than `new BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Java operators are only designed to only operate on primitive data types; they do not act on classes.  Since BigInteger is a class, arithmetic comparisons and operations can only be done through class methods.